# Using PHP PDO to INSERT INTO table - hangs on execute() statement

Tags: php, ios, mysql, json, pdo

I have been working on this one for about two days now. I am trying to setup a PHP backend for an iOS mobile app that I am testing, and I have already gotten a rudimentary version of what I am trying to do to work with `mysqli`, but I want to use `PDO` instead.

I am trying to store user information that I am sending from the app to the test server (on my computer). I have been able to figure out `UPDATE` and `SELECT` with `PDO` so far - but when I get to the step where my app makes a `POST` request to store information in the `mysql` database, what happens is as follows:

a.)It gets all the way to the `$stmt->execute()` line after I either pass the parameters to bind to the `execute()` function as an array of parameters, or I use `bindValue` to bind them all individually in a `foreach` loop before I try to `execute()`. If my code makes it to the part where it has not found a new user and tries to enter the information, this is what happens:

```
    $this->strforvalsie = substr($this->strforvalsie, 0, -1);
    $this->stforquee = substr($this->stforquee, 0, -1);
    $this->querystring = substr($this->querystring, 0, -1);

    $this->hh = $this->makeathing($this->stforquee, $this->querystring);

    echo "\n\n".$this->hh."\n\n";

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($this->hh);


    foreach ($this->arrayfordat as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bindValue( (string)$key, (string)$value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }

    echo "\n\n\n\n\n".json_encode($streetch)."\n\n\n\n\n\n";

    //return 2 - /*** I use this line to exit the code early...before the hang - to see what the variables look like. I will print the outputs below to help. ***/

    if($stmt->execute($streetch)) { /*** IT SEEMS TO HANG HERE AND NEVER MAKE IT TO THE RETURN STATEMENT WHICH IS FOR THE PURPOSES OF EXITING THE INSTANCE OF THE CLASS TO SEND A RESPONSE ***/
        return 3;
    }
    else {
        return 2;
    }
```

Here is the output from the echo statements exactly in order as it appears - and I will explain what I am doing (I'm hiding the values but they all look to be the ones that I want...I am mostly wondering about formatting issues...if I am formatting something wrong that is breaking my `POST` request to `mysql`:

```
/*** THIS LINE IS RESPONSIBLE FOR CREATING MY QUERY: $this->hh = $this->makeathing($this->stforquee, $this->querystring); Output below: ***/

INSERT INTO users(username,email,userfirst,userlast,updatedtime,usergender,fbverified,timezone,fbprofilelink,fblocale,fbid) VALUES(:username,:email,:userfirst,:userlast,:updatedtime,:usergender,:fbverified,:timezone,:fbprofilelink,:fblocale,:fbid)

/*** THIS IS WHAT A JSON OBJECT LOOKS LIKE OF THE ARRAY THAT I AM PASSING TO THE execute() FUNCTION - created by the line: echo "\n\n\n\n\n".json_encode($streetch)."\n\n\n\n\n\n"; Ouput below: ***/

{":username":"Eamon White",":email":"eamon.white7@gmail.com",":userfirst":"Eamon",":userlast":"White",":updatedtime":"2014-06-15T17:34:06+0000",":usergender":"male",":fbverified":"NO",":timezone":"-5",":fbprofilelink":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/891510963470\/",":fblocale":"en_US",":fbid":"891510963470"}
```

The most annoying part about all of this...and hopefully the most telling to anybody who can help...all the information gets successfully stored in the database in a perfectly acceptable way...it's just the program never seems to want to move to the `return` statement after it `execute()`s so I can get a response to handle on the app side. Any help would be greatly appreciated. To sum up the problem - can't get passed the damn `$stmt->execute()` statement :).

Answer (score 0):

Please add to your connection following attribute:
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Does it print some error out?

Comment: I think I figured it out - look at my answer lol - I already had that - it was just hanging there...`query` not `prepare` lol

Comment: Just in future I would add this attribute to your connection. It will print out the errors ;)

Comment: thanks - if ur still there - now im using this for my query statement `INSERT INTO users (username, email, userfirst, userlast, updatedtime, usergender, fbverified, timezone, fbprofilelink, fblocale, fbid) VALUES (:username, :email, :userfirst, :userlast, :updatedtime, :usergender, :fbverified, :timezone, :fbprofilelink, :fblocale, :fbid)` and im getting the below error:

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':username, :email, :userfirst, :userlast, :updatedtime, :usergender, :fbverified' at line 1`

Comment: my answer was wrong...let me know if u wanna help out...maybe u have time to chat...im new to PDO

Comment: actually looks like I needed to be using `bindParam` and not `bindValue` - ill keep you posted

Comment: totally not sure..experiencing hanging again if you have any idea what that might be...im using try catch...not getting errors from the PDOException though...just hanging

Comment: data is going into the database successfully again...it just wont stop hanging though

Comment: This is now pretty confusing ^^ 
If you have an successful connection just do following: 
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO(user, email, pass) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array("Me", "me@me.me", "password"));

Comment: yah sorry...I've tried with question marks...and the data always goes through - I am having to do it dynamically...just adding keys and values to an array and trying to pass it to the `execute()` function...I can't hardcode something like `$stmt->execute(array("Me", "me@me.me", "password"));` in my case...it will not work...it needs to be more variable.

Comment: i just realized I might not have pdo installed ... eeeek

Comment: And? What does the phpinfo() say?

Comment: I think I had a semi newb moment...I found the answer...its a very weird one that I didn't realize matters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes...I am a semi newb - funny enough...I am using these methods for responses in my code:

```
function getStatusCodeMessage($status)
{
// these could be stored in a .ini file and loaded
// via parse_ini_file()... however, this will suffice
// for an example
$codes = Array(
    100 => 'Continue',
    101 => 'Switching Protocols',
    200 => 'OK',
    201 => 'Created',
    202 => 'Accepted',
    203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',
    204 => 'No Content',
    205 => 'Reset Content',
    206 => 'Partial Content',
    300 => 'Multiple Choices',
    301 => 'Moved Permanently',
    302 => 'Found',
    303 => 'See Other',
    304 => 'Not Modified',
    305 => 'Use Proxy',
    306 => '(Unused)',
    307 => 'Temporary Redirect',
    400 => 'Bad Request',
    401 => 'Unauthorized',
    402 => 'Payment Required',
    403 => 'Forbidden',
    404 => 'Not Found',
    405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
    406 => 'Not Acceptable',
    407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
    408 => 'Request Timeout',
    409 => 'Conflict',
    410 => 'Gone',
    411 => 'Length Required',
    412 => 'Precondition Failed',
    413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
    414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
    415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
    416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
    417 => 'Expectation Failed',
    500 => 'Internal Server Error',
    501 => 'Not Implemented',
    502 => 'Bad Gateway',
    503 => 'Service Unavailable',
    504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
    505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported'
);

return (isset($codes[$status])) ? $codes[$status] : '';
}


// Helper method to send a HTTP response code/message
function sendResponse($status=null, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/html')
{
    $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . getStatusCodeMessage($status);
    header($status_header);
    header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
    print $body;
}
```

I was using the `100` response just to use something different so I could destinguish what was happening on my server side from my app - and the `100` response stands for "Continue" - as you can see above in the definitions for the numbers. I think that is actually very relevant...but until now I had no idea that it would be - I am just testing on my localhost. Curious as to why it matters but it solved my problem.